# pdo update statement - save and update value in same statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am storing the users last and current IP address / datetime in the database.  On successful login of a user I am running these two prepared statements.

Out of curiosity is there any way to perform this in one statement?

Would something like `lastIP = currIP, currIP = ?, dtLastLogin = dtCurrLogin, dtCurrLogin = UTC_TIMESTAMP()` be allowed due to its order?

```
// update user's last ip and last login date in db
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET lastIP = currIP, dtLastLogin = dtCurrLogin WHERE account_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($account_id));

// update user's current ip and current login date in db
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET currIP = ?, dtCurrLogin = UTC_TIMESTAMP() WHERE account_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $account_id));
```

Comment: In theory that should be fine. Why don't you do a dry run with standard SQL to see if it works without PDO, then do it with PDO if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with mysql, you could do this in one sql.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET lastIP = currIP, currIP = ?, dtLastLogin = dtCurrLogin , dtCurrLogin = UTC_TIMESTAMP() WHERE account_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $account_id));
```

But note ***the order is important***.

Comment: Nice.. thanks for clearing that up.  I figured if it was legit then order would indeed be important.  One less call to the db is always good.